# Proof of $\log_xy=\frac{\log_zy}{\log_zx}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Why is $\log_xy=\frac{\log_zy}{\log_zx}$? Can we prove this using the laws of exponents?

Comment: What you wrote is not true, if $X\neq x$.  Perhaps you mean to ask why $\log_x Y=\frac{\log_X Y}{\log_X x}$, or why $\log_x x=1$.

Comment: You seem to be using lower-case $x$ and capital $X$ to refer to the same thing.  That shouldn't be done.  In standard usage, mathematical notation is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $x^a=y$, $z^b=x$ and $z^c=y$. Then $z^{ab}=(z^b)^a=x^a=y=z^c$ so that $ab=c$.

Answer (score 9):

I will presume that what was meant was $\displaystyle\log_x y = \frac{\log_z y}{\log_z x}$.

Notice that this is true if and only if $(\log_x y)(\log_z x) = \log_z y$, and that holds if and only if $\displaystyle z^{(\log_x y)(\log_z x)}=y$.

So
$$
z^{\Big((\log_x y)(\log_z x)\Big)} = \Big(z^{\log_z x}\Big)^{\log_x y} = x^{\log_x y} = y.
$$

Comment: Also $\log_{z}x^\log_{x}y = \log_{z}y$ which you can then simplify to $y=y$ (And could someone edit this, because I am not understanding the programming)

Comment: @Alex : You can edit your own comment within five minutes of posting it, but not after that, and others can't edit it.  It seems you mean $\log_z (x^{\log_x y}) = \log_z y$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition,
log<sub>z</sub> x<sup>log<sub>x</sub>y</sup> = log<sub>z</sub> y, also by definition we have, log<sub>z</sub> x<sup>log<sub>x</sub>y</sup> = log<sub>x</sub>y*log<sub>z</sub>x. So log<sub>z</sub>y = log<sub>x</sub>y*log<sub>z</sub>x. With division this gives us the result: log<sub>z</sub>y/log<sub>z</sub>x = log<sub>x</sub>y

Comment: I don't think that second statement is "by definition".  That is a _consequence of_ the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrate: $ \log_xy=\frac{\log_ay}{\log_ax}; x,y,a \in \mathbb{R} $

We initially have:$$ f(x,y)= \log_xy$$ 
We transform it to the exponential form: $$ x^{f(x,y)}=y$$
We apply logarithm of base $a$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ on both sides of the equation:$$\log_a{x^{f(x,y)}}=\log_ay$$
Applying the exponential property: $\log_ab^c=c\log_ab$ we have: $$ f(x,y) \log_ax=\log_ay$$
Getting $f(x,y)$ $$ f(x,y)=\frac{\log_ay}{\log_ax} $$

We initially have that $f(x,y)=\log_xy$ and then we got $f(x)=\frac{\log_ay}{\log_ax}$, so:
$$ \log_xy = \frac{\log_ay}{\log_ax} \\ Q.E.D.$$

** If there are words that are not appropriated in this demonstration please let me know. I'm not English speaker!  **